# How to Completely End a Test in Node Mocha Without Continuing

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

How do I force a Mochajs test to end completely without continuing on to the next tests. A scenario could be prevent any further tests if the environment was accidentally set to production and I need to prevent the tests from continuing.

I've tried throwing Errors but those don't stop the entire test because it's running asynchronously.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The kind of "test" you are talking about --- namely checking whether the environment is properly set for the test suite to run --- should be done in a `before` hook. (Or perhaps in a `beforeEach` hook but `before` seems more appropriate to do what you are describing.)

However, it would be better to use this `before` hook to set an isolated environment to run your test suite with. It would take the form:

```
describe("suite", function () {
    before(function () {
        // Set the environment for testing here.
        // e.g. Connect to a test database, etc.
    });

    it("blah", ...
});
```

If there is some overriding reason that makes it so that you cannot create a test environment with a hook and you *must* perform a check instead you could do it like this:

```
describe("suite", function () {
    before(function () {
        if (production_environment)
            throw new Error("production environment! Aborting!");
    });

    it("blah", ...
});
```

A failure in the `before` hook will prevent the execution of any callbacks given to `it`. At most, Mocha will perform the `after` hook (if you specify one) to perform cleanup after the failure.

Note that whether the `before` hook is asynchronous or not does not matter. (Nor does it matter whether your tests are asynchronous.) If you write it correctly (and call `done` when you are done, if it is asynchronous), Mocha will detect that an error occurred in the hook and won't execute tests.

And the fact that Mocha continues testing after you have a failure in a *test* (in a callback to `it`) is not dependent on whether the tests are asynchronous. Mocha does not interpret a failure of a *test* as a reason to stop the whole suite. It will continue trying to execute tests even if an earlier test has failed. (As I said above, a failure in a *hook* is a different matter.)

Comment: Mocha has added a `skip()` method which they document using in what seems to be pretty much this situation. Quoting from the end of the [Inclusive Tests](https://mochajs.org/#inclusive-tests) section: "You may also skip at runtime using `this.skip()`. If a test needs an environment or configuration which cannot be detected beforehand, a runtime skip is appropriate. For example... _{code rather similar to this answer}_...Before Mocha v3.0.0, this.skip() was not supported in asynchronous tests and hooks."

Comment: I'm well aware of `skip` but I don't think it is well adapted to the scenario the OP is describing. Someone having set the environment to "production" rather than "testing" can have some pretty damaging consequences. `skip` tells Mocha "just skip this" but otherwise does not convey that **there's been a serious screw up somewhere**. Raising an exception in a hook is the appropriate way to make the developers aware of the screw up. Mocha will fail and loudly report the exception it got.

Answer (score 7):

As of the [mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#-exit), you can add `--exit` flag when you are executing the tests.
It will stop the execution whenever all the tests have been executed successfully or not.

ex:

```sh
mocha **/*.spec.js --exit
```

Answer (score 6):

I generally agree with Glen, but since you have a decent use case, you should be able to trigger node to exit with the `process.exit()` command. See http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code. You can use it like so:

```
process.exit(1);
```

Comment: Seems like a very nasty way to exit. This won't allow mocha to do it's cleanup

Comment: it also doesn't work.  if placed in between `describe`s it prevents the tests from running completely and if placed within an `it`, doesn't exit at all